# How can I keep the line breaks (formatting) of an element appended to a list via a contenteditable div input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've a bit of a problem. I'm currently programming a list, where users can enter some hints/messages. This works quite well but there is a problem I've found and I don't like it.

To prevent any HTML input, I've implemented some stuff inside a `paste` function that gives me any plain text in case there is HTML. When I now copy some code that has multiple lines like:

```
$( "button" ).click( function () {
    let template = $( "#template" ).clone();

  template.removeAttr("id");
    template.html( input.html() );

  input.empty();
    $( "#wrapper" ).append( template );
} );
```

and paste it into my `contenteditable div`, the line formatting is still there. If I now press my button to append it to the list, the formatting is completely gone and everything is in one single line.

I'm looking now for a way to fix this. Does anyone has an idea how I prevent loosing any of the line breaks and formatting?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  let input = $("#input");

  $("button").click(function() {
    let template = $("#template").clone();

    template.removeAttr("id");
    template.html(input.html());

    input.empty();
    $("#wrapper").append(template);
  });

  input.on("paste", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let clipboardText = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');

    document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, clipboardText.replace(/\t/g, "    "));
  });
});
```

```css
[contenteditable=true] {
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  display: block;
  color: #aaaaaa;
}

#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 350px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.entry {
  display: flex;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  padding: 4px;
}

#template {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <span id="template" class="entry"></span>
</div>
<div id="input" placeholder="Write a message..." contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true"></div>
<button>Add to list</button>
```

**Edit**

I'm already replacing tabs by whitespaces to move around a possible issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add `white-space: pre;` to your css `.entry` class, like so:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  let input = $("#input");

  $("button").click(function() {
    let template = $("#template").clone();

    template.removeAttr("id");
    template.html(input.html());

    input.empty();
    $("#wrapper").append(template);
  });

  input.on("paste", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let clipboardText = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');

    document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, clipboardText.replace(/\t/g, "    "));
  });
});
```

```css
[contenteditable=true] {
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  display: block;
  color: #aaaaaa;
}

#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 350px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.entry {
  display: flex;
  white-space: pre;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  padding: 4px;
}

#template {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <span id="template" class="entry"></span>
</div>
<div id="input" placeholder="Write a message..." contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true"></div>
<button>Add to list</button>
```

Using `white-space: pre` will tell the browser to preserve white space, and text will only wrap on line breaks. Acts like the `<pre>` tag in HTML.

Comment: Can you tell me the difference between pre and pre-wrap in this case? Which is better to use?

Comment: I'll be honest, the way they [describe the behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) is a bit obscure to me. So, I usually use the one that seems to fulfill my needs best. Guess I should probably brush up on this particular css property :)

Comment: After taking a closer look, it seems that with pre-wrap, the text is wrapped according to the size of the container. Whereas, with pre, the original formatting is preserved, wrapping exactly where the original text did.

Comment: Alright I understand. Thanks a lot. I'll choose pre-wrap to prevent overflow during the wrapping.